# How to add input number in a text field and submitting answer in a label or text box in iOS

Tags: ios, uitextfield, addition

I am having trouble trying to add a number inputted in a text box to add itself.

I have created two outlets - one where to input the number and the second where the answer shows. 
I also created a outlet action for the button where to submit it.

Now when I input a number, since its a string its a string it just puts it together like this. 
Enter number 10,  outcome is 1010.

It does not add itself. I want an outcome of 20.

@IBOutlet weak var inputField: UITextField!

```
@IBAction func addButton(sender: AnyObject) {

    addAnswerBox.text = inputField.text + inputField.text

}

@IBOutlet weak var addAnswerBox: UITextField!
```

}

Answer (score 1):

What you have to do is convert the string to an int. Once you do that, then you can get 10 + 10.

This is what I mean:

```
let a:Int? = inputField.text.toInt()
let b:Int? = inputField.text.toInt()

if a && b {
    var ans = a! + b!
    answerLabel.text = "Answer is \(ans)"
} else {
    answerLabel.text = "Input values are not numberic"
}
```

Comment: Updated my answer. Lemme know if it helps

Comment: Ok I cleaned it up and got this working but it only adds once and I cant keep adding the same number.

Comment: How do you add it? The correct way should be: myInt += myValue

Comment: var numberResults = 0
        var convertedNumber = inputField.text.toInt()
        
        numberResults = convertedNumber! + convertedNumber!
        addAnswerBox.text = "\(numberResults)"        
    }
    
    @IBOutlet weak var addAnswerBox: UITextField!
}

Comment: It's a bit hard to read. Can you post it in your question please?

Answer (score 0):

You need to take the IntValue from the string.

```
addAnswerBox.text = "\(inputField.text.intValue + inputField.text.intValue)"
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I needed to make a class as add so that way I dont reference it a 0.
Then I had to create a func that adds the results then call it back on the button.

Comment: Thank you for helping out, I needed to create a class, which I thought in the first place. Then create a function in that class that adds var then call it back to the function of the button.